# Off canvas with Foundation4

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have been working on Foundation 4 framework.I just want to know whether off canvas layout system is required for this version or not. As per my knowledge its not required because they have added mobile support with 'Mobile First' theme.

Please correct if i am wrong.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off Canvas Layouts is not required for Foundation 4 because it was written for version 3. But while it was written for V3 it can work with F4. I know, and not only by opinion, but as a matter of fact, as I have played with it already and have a proto using F4 with off canvas layout specifically with the sliding panel [similar to this](http://www.zurb.com/playground/playground/off-canvas/offcanvas-4.html).

Answer (score 1):

For better UI in small devices [Off Canvas Layout](http://www.zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts) is awesome. Like if You hit a button and a panel slides in from the left (or depending on how you look at it, the main panel slides out of the way). You should really use it. And Of course, if you have downloaded the latest release from [github repo](https://github.com/zurb/foundation) or via [website](http://foundation.zurb.com/) it is already come with Zurb Foundation 4.

Comment: Off Canvas Layout does not come out-of-the-box in F4. I thought at first it's "as far as I know" but hey I got intrigued and I said it would be fantastic if it is. But it is NOT, at least not as of this date. [This page](http://foundation.zurb.com/off-canvas.php) warns us of its use with F4. [This page](http://www.zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts) specifically mention that Off Canvas is compatible with F3.